# Are there common testing standards for react.js components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm testing **Hero** component using jest & enzyme. I thought to my mind that I can do the same thing in the two ways.

For example, I want to get a component's state.

```
test('Test description', () => {
    const element = shallow(
        <Hero />
    );

    // 1
    expect(element.state()).toBeTruthy();
    // 2
    expect(element.instance().state).toBeTruthy();
});
```

I have two variants to write this code: using .instance().state or .state(). Probably there are recommendations how to write code like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`state()` is a shortcut for `instance().state`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/v2.9.1/src/ReactWrapper.jsx#L562-L569) that provides meaningful error message in case it's called on wrong wrapper.

Since `state()` exists in Enzyme API, it's intended to be used for this purpose. It takes less characters to type than `instance().state`.